# How can a transformer convert the voltage of the same wire before and after connection?

Tags: transformer, ac

Today I discovered a very strange thing, this transformer in the picture below, has 3 phases as input, and the output varies as you can see in the picture, the weird thing is that when I measure the voltage across every two phases before connecting them to the transformer I get 380v, but when I do so after connecting them, I get different values, the very same wire goes from high voltage to 0 voltage, is this correct? I couldn't believe it until I touched the wire and didn't get a shock! How does this work?
 [image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9xEMi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: *I get different values* - how different - please state before measurements and after measurements.

Comment: After connecting the wires, I get the numbers written on transformer, 0, 220, 380.

Comment: That is NOT a 3-phase transformer. It is a single-phase transformer with three windings -- a primary that can vary anywhere from 220 to 550 V (+/- 20V) and two secondaries.

Comment: @Dave Tweed, can you please explain this to me in details?

Comment: "the very same wire goes from high voltage to 0 voltage" with respect to what? I suspect that a fuse has blown in one of the phases and that the point marked zero on the transformer is grounded.

Comment: Touching the wire to verify 0V is not a recommended method to see if there's still 380V on it.

Comment: The label itself is a fairly detailed drawing of the construction of the transformer. The thick black bars represent the windings. What part of it is not clear to you? BTW, this is a massive (5400W) transformer. What are you going to use it for?

Comment: Thank you all, but it seems like no one has understood my question, unfortunately.

Comment: Definitely it isn't a 3phase transformer and touching presumably de-energized wires is a terrible idea.
--_"when I measure the voltage across every two phases before connecting them to the transformer I get 380v"_: correct, you're not loading your pahses with nothing
--_"after connecting the very same wire goes from high voltage to 0 voltage"_: the only way I can think it can happen is if the winding you're using is shortcircuited. 

But what you said doesn't match with the drawing you posted, please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

> After connecting the wires, I get the numbers written on transformer, 0, 220, 380.

It's a single phase transformer.

The primary winding also works like an auto transformer.

[image]

When 380 V is applied between terminals '0' and '380', the voltages between '0' and the other terminals will read 20, 20, 220, 280, 440, 500 and 550 V.